# using xargs pass arguments to sub shell with pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, command-line-arguments, xargs, sh

I want to rename a number of files. I think I can use xargs to do it.

```
find ./ -name "upload.log-*" 
./upload.log-20180622.gz-20180624.gz-20180626.gz
./upload.log-20180624.gz-20180626.gz
./upload.log-20180620.gz-20180622.gz-20180624.gz-20180626.gz
./upload.log-20180621.gz-20180623.gz-20180625.gz-20180627.gz

find ./ -name "upload.log-*" -print | cut -d"-" -f-2
./upload.log-20180622.gz
./upload.log-20180624.gz
./upload.log-20180620.gz
./upload.log-20180621.gz
```

I am trying the following but it does not seem to be working

```
find ./ -name "upload.log-*" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c "echo $1 $(echo $1 | cut -d"-" -f-2)" "{}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does what I need it to do

```
find ./ -name "cleanup.log-*" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'mv "$1" $(echo {} | cut -d"-" -f-2)' - {}
```

The tricky bit was converting the xargs replacement `-I {}` string into arguments for the xargs command `sh -c ...`.
I did this by putting a no option argument `-`, at the end of the command before the replacement string `{}`.

Thus my command to xargs is the following.
 `sh -c 'mv "$1" $(echo {} | cut -d"-" -f-2)' - {}`

I used this to test what I wanted befor running the move command

```
find ./ -name "upload.log-*" | xargs -I '{}' sh -c 'echo "$1" $(echo {} | cut -d"-" -f-2)' - {}
```

I found this site helpful in understanding how to solve this problem

[https://explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find%20.%2F%20-name%20%22cleanup.log-*%22%20%7C%20xargs%20-I%20%27%7B%7D%27%20sh%20-c%20%27mv%20%22%241%22%20%24%28echo%20%7B%7D%20%7C%20cut%20-d%22-%22%20-f-2%29%27%20-%20%7B%7D)